# AS3 Timestamp isn't correct

Tags: actionscript-3, unix-timestamp

I'm trying to get the current unix timestamp in AS3 via:

```
var date:Date = new Date();
var unix:int = date.time;

trace(unix);
```

For some reason I get:

```
2775219874
```

But when I use `time()` in PHP around the same time, I get:

```
1321330282
```

I don't understand?

I could of course request the timestamp from PHP via `URLLoader`, but I'd rather get it working properly without needing this if possible.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The issue in my question was being caused by assigning `date.time` to `int` instead of `Number`.

See below for demo of assigning `date.time` to a variable:

```
var date:Date = new Date();

var uintVal:uint = date.time;
var intVal:int = date.time;
var numVal:Number = date.time;

trace(uintVal);     // 2776669556
trace(intVal);      // -1518297740
trace(numVal);      // 1321331629428
```

Comment: @Chris I can't for another two days :(

Comment: oh yeah, sorry forgot about that!

Comment: So which one should we use to match php time() ?

Comment: @PapaDeBeau `Number`.

Answer (score 0):

Flash should return the numbers of milliseconds so you should get something like 1321330797782 (that's what I'm getting here). Is your computer's time correct? If it is, just try closing and reopening Flash because there's something really wrong with the time your are getting (it's some time in 1970).

The PHP time is correct.

Comment: I figured it would be something related to my time, however my time seems fine at `15th November 2011 3:24PM`.